# Why is the second output 6?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, pass-by-reference

```
void addOne(int &y)
{
    y = y + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    addOne(x);
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if this is a basic question. But why does y = y + 1 is 6?

Comment: You might want to get a [decent book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/253056) and read the chapter on *references*.

Comment: That is what I did. But I really dont get this part in the notes. That is why I need more people to assist me here to understand better..sorry

Comment: `addOne` just adds 1 to whatever `int` variable you pass to it (*by reference*). So in this case you pass `x`, which has a value of 5, and it has 1 added to it to become 6.

Comment: I see. But why does the computer ignore the variable y infornt? Wont it be like 5 = 5 + 1?

Comment: This is just how assignment works - the right hand side is first evaluated, and then the result of this evaluation is *assigned* to the left hand side. So it's `y = 5 + 1`.

Comment: do you understand `x = 7;` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What might help, initially, is to think of **references** as syntactic sugar for **pointers**.

Consider the following:

```
int main() {
    int x = 5;
    int *px = &x;
    *px = 8;

    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints out `8`, as you would expect. (If you didn't expect that then it might be worth reading an [introduction to pointers](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/67-introduction-to-pointers/) before tackling references.)

A reference variable, then, can be thought of as a pointer variable whose syntax is that of a regular variable. The following is equivalent to the previous example:

```
int main() {
    int x = 5;
    int &rx = x;
    rx = 8;

    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

That is, `rx` becomes a *reference to* `x`, and thus whenever you change `rx`, you change `x` as well, because both names refer to the same thing... or in other words, `rx` is bound to a *memory location*, **not** a value, and setting `rx` changes *what is at that memory location*.

In a sense, `rx` is sort of invisible - it doesn't have an existence of its own, it only exists in terms of what `x` is (which is why you have to initialize a reference when it's declared, i.e. you can't do `int &rx;` in a function and leave it hanging).

So when you have:

```
void addOne(int &y)
{
    y = y + 1;
}
```

This is a function whose parameter is a *reference* to what is passed in... and so when the parameter reference is changed, that which the reference refers to is also changed.

And so when you call it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    addOne(x);
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This calls `addOne` with `x`, thus initializing the `int &` reference `y` to `x`, and so whenever `y` is changed, `x` is changed... and so `x` changes from `5` to `5 + 1`, i.e. `6`.

You can think of it as equivalent to the following:

```
void addOne(int *py)
{
    *py = *py + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    addOne(&x);
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

To see why you'd use a reference vs. a pointer, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in).

Answer (score 1):

A reference is not an independent variable, you should consider it to *literally* be another. So when you pass x to function addOne, the reference called y literally becomes x (how this works behind the screens is less important right now).

So when you increase y by one, what you are really doing is increasing x. That's why x is 6, after the call to addOne.

Comment: When 5 is passed, the equation will be 5=5+1? Or I am wrong?

Comment: You are not doing math, you are programming. In that expression you tell the machine to take the _variable_ that currently holds value 5, add 1, and store the result back into the same variable. The fact that some notation is shared with mathematical expressions does not make a computer language into a direct expression of the same concepts you have in math, and you should not interpret it in the same way at all.

Comment: I see. So the computer will ignore the value 5 passed to the variable itself?

Comment: Hardly. But I think you are struggling very much with extremely basic concepts. Again, don't treat this as a set of mathematical equations that should somehow balance out to be true. Instead, read it as a series of mechanical steps the machine should take, in order. You tell the machine there is a memory location that you call x. You tell it that memory location should have value 5. Then you tell it to increase that memory location by one.

Comment: Okay..I think I slowly understand what you meant by now. I will practice this more on pc and see what other outcome i get

Comment: @Student `5` is not passed to anything.  When you write `y` it means *a variable called `y`*, it does not mean the contents of that variable.   What you do with the variable depends on what you do with it. If you go `y + 1` then it retrieves the value stored in the variable so it can add 1. If you go `y = 9` then it stores a new value in the variable, without retrieving the old stored value.

Comment: replace the word "variable" with "memory location" if it helps you to understand